# List<dynamic> to List<LatLng> in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new at Flutter dev.

I got a very simple issue.
I want to map a *List<dynamic>* to a *List<LatLng>* with this

```
var latLngCoordinates = coordinates.map((coord) => LatLng(coord[0], coord[1])).toList();
```

If I debug the code I got a List<dynamic> where each entry is *LatLng* object.
How can I get a *List<LatLng>* instead of a *List<dynamic>* one for **latLngCoordinates**?

Thanks,
FB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the type `<LatLng>` to the `map` function:

```
var latLngCoordinates = coordinates.map<LatLng>((coord) => LatLng(coord[0], coord[1])).toList();
```

Comment: oh, no type inference? Very interesting

Comment: yes, if you want a specific type of list as a result, you need to explicitly set the type, it is not inferred

Answer (score 1):

you can also use `as List<LatLng>`

```
var latLngCoordinates = coordinates.map((coord) => LatLng(coord[0], coord[1])).toList() as List<LatLng>;
```